# NodeJS, get client IP on TLS server

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, tls1.2

I have the following `Node.JS` for creating a `TLS server` which pipes data to another server:

```
var server = net.createServer(function (localsocket) {

  var remotesocket = tls.connect(options, function() {

    remotesocket.on('data', function(data) {
      var flushed = localsocket.write(data);
      if (!flushed) {
        remotesocket.pause();
      }
    });

    remotesocket.on('drain', function() {
      localsocket.resume();
    });

    remotesocket.on('close', function(had_error) {
      localsocket.end();
    });

  });

  localsocket.on('data', function (data) {
    var flushed = remotesocket.write(data);
    if (!flushed) {
      localsocket.pause();
    }
  });

  localsocket.on('drain', function() {
    remotesocket.resume();
  });

  localsocket.on('close', function(had_error) {
    remotesocket.end();
  });

});
```

Everything seems to work fine, but I would like to change `options` according to client IPs.

I've tried to do `console.log(localsocket)`, but that only gives me my servers local IP, and not clients sending packets to my `TLS server`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [connectListener](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_connection) (the function which is given to createServer) gets the `socket_object` which is an object of type [net.Socket](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket). There is a property [remoteAddress](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_remoteaddress) which has the address of the remote host.

Example:

```
var server = net.createServer(function (localsocket) {
    console.log(localsocket.remoteAddress);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Works. Tried to do simple `console.log(localsocket)` but that didn't contain the value apparently.